# FTP recursive download via system commands on Windows

Tags: windows, ftp, system

I am looking for a way to download everything from a directory on a FTP server including the contains of all the subdirectories using the windows system ftp commands.

For example,

```
dir_path = /FTP/dir1/
```

dir1 contains are:

```
dir1
+--dir1
+--dir2
|  +--files
+dir2
 +--more files
```

Is there a command like `ftp _command_` or any convenient means that would download, as for this example, files and more files while keeping the original FTP hierarchy?

Answer (score -1):

1. Open an Explorer (folder) window
2. Type ftp://domain.com
3. Enter username and password
4. Copy and paste folder

Or use FileZilla for a faster and more reliable FTP experience!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Sadly, I have to implement this feature in my own c++ programm, so using a third-party software is not an option right now.